# UTF-8 encoding on Windows and Mac messes characters

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to use my Windows (7 64bit) machine to obtain data from the Itunes API and process this data on my Mac (64bit El Capitan). I am using the RJSONIO package to extract the names of the applications, they are from different countries in different languages. I attached a minimal examples with a few applications only. My preferred encoding is UTF-8.

```
library(RJSONIO)

getall<-function(ID){
u<-ID
lapply(X = u, function(u){
    dat <- fromJSON(u, encoding = "UTF-8")
    Name<-try(dat$results[[1]]$trackName)
    Artistname<-try(dat$results[[1]]$artistName)
    Seller<-try(dat$results[[1]]$sellerName)
    results<-return(list(Name, Artistname,Seller))
    })
}

apps1<-c("https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=335549244", "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=362032276", "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=353410020", "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=350146139","https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=358942449", "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=359871187")
    system.time(itunesNew<-data.frame(matrix(unlist(getall(ID = apps1), use.names = FALSE), nrow = length(apps1), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE),stringsAsFactors=FALSE, byrow=T))
    colnames(itunesNew)<-c("Name", "Artistname","Seller")
    itunesnew2<-cbind(apps1, itunesNew)
```

I am using R with R Studio (both the most recent versions) and set standard encoding to UTF-8 in the global options. I was not able to set my locale to UTF-8 using

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", 'en_GB.UTF-8')
```

or other versions in R. I also tried to download the data in "latin1" (it looks alright then on the PC), but messed up on the mac (setting encoding to latin1 in R Studio.).

**Questions**:

1. Is there a way to work with the data on both machines using UTF-8?
2. Are there other options to work on both machines?
3. More general: is UTF-8 the encoding one should prefer for data like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have my Windows VM handy but try this (it uses `jsonlite` & `dplyr` on both your systems to see if it helps (I ran it on OS X):

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

"%||%" <- function(a, b) { if (!is.null(a)) a else b }

apps <- c("https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=335549244", 
          "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=362032276", 
          "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=353410020", 
          "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=350146139",
          "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=358942449", 
          "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=359871187")

bind_rows(lapply(apps, function(x) {
  res <- jsonlite::fromJSON(x, flatten=TRUE)$results
  data_frame(name=res$trackName %||% NA,
             artist_name=res$sellerName %||% NA,
             seller=res$sellerName %||% NA)
})) -> dat

glimpse(dat)

## Observations: 6
## Variables: 3
## $ name        (chr) "A+ the Waverley Novels Collection (15Books)", "A+ 中國養生寶典[卷一]", "...
## $ artist_name (chr) "rice mi", "CHEUNG PUI MAN", "CHEUNG PUI MAN", "CHEUNG PUI MAN", ...
## $ seller      (chr) "rice mi", "CHEUNG PUI MAN", "CHEUNG PUI MAN", "CHEUNG PUI MAN", ...
```

Comment: This solves the problem! I can scrape it on both, windows and OS and can load them without any problems on both systems. Thank you!